# What is the default gradient in Android buttons?

Tags: android, button, gradient

I'm trying to set a button to have rounded corners and keep the default gradient color. Unfortunately I can't just not set the background color in the .xml drawable or else it goes black. So does anyone know what the default color is? And if not how I can round the corner and keep the default color?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the default ressources used on buttons on the [android drawable site](http://androiddrawables.com/Buttons.html). They are mostly 9-patch images, see [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for details.